# Что такое package identifier for Android и bundle identifier for iOS?

Tags: android, ios, phonegap

При создании проекта в PhoneGap есть пункт с указанием ID проекта в стиле "домен наоборот", например: "com.phonegap.helloworld.". В руководстве указано что это этот ID используется для **package identifier for Android** и **bundle identifier for iOS** - что это значит?

> Optionally enter a project ID in the ID text field. If you choose not
>   to enter a project ID, your project will be given a default ID of
>   com.phonegap.helloworld. This ID field will be used for the package
>   identifier for Android and the bundle identifier for iOS and is
>   typically in reverse domain style.

[Источник](http://docs.phonegap.com/references/desktop-app/create-project/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В случае андроида это да, перевёрнутый адрес, используемый как `package` для проекта. По сути своей это путь к корневому каталогу, в коем хранятся исходники (т.е. файлы с кодом).

Также этот `package identifier` используется в качестве ID приложения в сторе и на девайсе. Т.е. любое приложение может быть найдено в маркете по ссылке вида

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=%PACKAGE_NAME%
```

например https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.dante.scpfoundation, где `ru.dante.scpfoundation` - это и есть `package identifier`

С другой стороны, при сборке проекта `package identifier` можно менять и он не будет совпадать со структурой папок проекта. Так что в общем случае сей идентификатор - ID приложения в сторе/на девайсе

С вероятностью 95% на иОС всё тоже самое

Comment: ну про 95% вы загнули. 92-93%, не больше